# What would you say if tomorrow or yesterday were a milestone moment for you?

Tags: future-time, time-reference

If today were your and your partner's 5th anniversary you would say:

- "It's been 5 years since we started dating"

or

- "We've been dating for 5 years already"

or some might say:

- "It's 5 years since we started dating."

But what way would you say the same thing, if the anniversary were tomorrow or yesterday? (if there are numerous ways, please, feel free to share them all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way is exactly the same, only adding "*as of tomorrow/yesterday*" to the beginning or end. The grammar doesn't need to change because five years plus or minus one day is *basically* the same as five years.

However, if someone's talking about a relatively significant time difference between the "how long ago" and the "as of..." time gap, then precision in grammar becomes more important.

Take the slightly different example:

> "We've been dating for **three days** already."

Now, if we add "as of yesterday" or "as of tomorrow", it no longer feels right to use present tenses since the difference between 3 and 4 days or between 2 and 3 days, respectively, is significant and requires grammatical precision.

> As of tomorrow, it **will have been** three days since we started dating.
> As of tomorrow, we **will have been** dating for three days already.
> As of tomorrow, it **will be** three days since we started dating.
>
> As of yesterday, it **had been** three days since we started dating.
> As of yesterday, we **had been dating** for three days already.
> As of yesterday, it **was** three days since we started dating.

Comment: Thank you! I like your point about the span of 5 years which includes both tomorrow and yesterday and doesn't need a change of grammar.

Comment: I have two remarks, though:
First: to be honest, I don't see any  meaningful difference between "As of tomorrow, it will have been three days since we started dating." and "As of tomorrow, it will be three days since we started dating.", the same goes for "As of yesterday, it had been three days since we started dating." and "As of yesterday, it was three days since we started dating.". Is there any real difference?
Second: Are there any synonyms for "as of yesterday/tomorrow", I can think of "by yesterday/tomorrow". Is it a good one?

Comment: Although, maybe there's no difference at all. You know, it seems to me that there's no difference in the meaning between "It's been 5 years since we started dating" and "It's 5 years since we started dating.", so, might it be that there's an analogous situation here, meaning both "As of tomorrow, it will have been three days since we started dating." and "As of tomorrow, it will be three days since we started dating." virtually have the same meaning, as well as the other two sentences about the past?

Comment: "We've been dating for five years tomorrow" works for me. Also, I find the 'already' unnecessary unless you particularly want to stress that the time has gone quickly.